# docker run - invalid reference format in Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell, docker

I am trying to execute the following command in Powershell of Windows 10

```
docker run -d --name zookeeper-server \ --network app-tier \ bitnami/zookeeper:latest
```

I am getting **Invalid Reference Format** error.

I think there is a problem with **\**. What is the windows version of the above command?

Edit: When I put the line breaks after the \, I get the following error:

```
At line:2 char:7
+     --network app-tier \
+       ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:2 char:7
+     --network app-tier \
+       ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'network' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'\'` usually stand in front of line breaks. There are no line breaks in your command line. What are the backslashes for, then?

Comment: @Tomalak yes, but when I put the line breaks after \, I am getting a different error. See the updated question

Comment: The escape character in Powershell is the backtick (`). If you want line-continuation, use the backtick instead of the backslash. But I don't see a reason for having a multi-line command here, so maybe remove the backslashes entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the backslashes. There's no character to escape so in bash you are passing a literal space as an argument, breaking the next parameter, so docker would try to run an image named "`--network`" (there's a leading space there) which is an invalid syntax or "reference" for an image. In powershell, it's likely passing the backslash itself as an arguement, meaning docker is looking for an image named "`\`", which again is an invalid "reference" for an image.

```
docker run -d --name zookeeper-server --network app-tier bitnami/zookeeper:latest
```

Comment: You can use backticks `\``

Comment: Excellent! This solution of removing the backslashes while working on Docker using Windows Powershell resolved the issue for me. Thank you so much!